# valgrind: Use of unitialized value from std::string::assign

Tags: c++, std, valgrind

valgrind reports the error for the follow code

```
void test(const std::vector<string> &strvec) {
  string val;
  if (strvec.size() > 0) {
    val = strvec.front(); // use of uninitialized value of size 8
  }
}
```

Sorry that I cannot post the full code because it depends on lots of other things. This is just a simple code snip.

Since valgrind does not report any error about size() check, so I think
I should be able to get its front. But I do not understand why it complains accessing uninitialized values.

Comment: If you make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) using this snippet does valgrind still give the same output?

Comment: Unrelated, I think `if (!strvec.empty()) {` is the more idiomatic check/test.

Comment: We need to see how `strvec` and its content is defined, as @JamesAdkison says.

Comment: You don't have any multithreading in play here, do you?

Comment: I will try make a simplified example. My puzzle is that std's constructors should make all related data initialized. If so, std::assign should not depend on any undefined data. @BenVoigt: the data are not shared by other threads.

Comment: @JoeC: So your application does have multiple threads, but the particular vector being passed as a parameter is not (intentionally) shared?

Comment: I've a feeling you have some threading or memory management error and it just happens to manifest as corruption of this vector.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I think valgrind checks uninitialized issues by checking some bits in memory. In multi-thread case, some one could read the data before it is fully initialized. In my case the init and the access happen sequentally, I am not sure how this can happy. Also, I can consistently reproduce the issue. In multithreading case, this should be sporadic, right?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

In terms of 
  https://blog.mozilla.org/nnethercote/2009/02/27/eliminating-undefined-values-with-valgrind-the-easy-way/

Actually when any actions depend on an earlier jump caused by accessing undefined variables, it reports the same error for those actions.

In my case, this error depends on an if-check that is far away from here, but the code path indeed depends on that one.

Does valgrind have an option to report 'root-cause'?

Comment: Asking a question in an answer will likely not yield very good results. If you haven't already found an answer you would do well to ask a new question.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35217336/can-valgrind-report-only-the-root-cause-of-reading-uninit-var